# Create dproj from command line

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-2010, batch-build

I wanted to invest a few hours to create a batch file that creates the base compiling and deployment setup for our Delphi2010 environment on a new computer.
My deployment procedure uses msbuild so I think I need the dproj files for this
task. These files are not checked into our svn system and are normally created on the fly by the Delphi environment when the project is opened the first time (this is what I want to do in a batch file...).

Any clue how that can be done via the command line?
Or is there any tool that is able to do that (I found dprojMaker but the
links on google are broken...)

Comment: Check the .dproj files into svn. That way you'll be able to keep track of any changes you make, and apply any global settings, e.g. compiler options, conditionals.

Comment: I'm the author of DprojMaker, but its quite old, although the concept still holds water. I was looking the other day to solving the nuisance of frames that are in the dpr but don't get seen by the IDE when you open the corresponding form. What trouble are you having with DprojMaker?

Comment: @BrianFrost: the link on your blog
http://www.appliedrelaytesting.co.uk/software/DprojMaker/DprojMaker.zip
does not point to a valid zip file...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: could be an option I'll check that out and see if there are any global paths within that file that would create incompatibilities if there are paths that are different in our development pc's....

Comment: That would provide a good opportunity to remove any such things. After all, you want to be confident that you are all building the same thing.

Comment: @mrabat: Sorry about that - fixed. Bear in mind that I made it when XE2 was king :-) but it should still work ok as long as you create a template using a recent dproj file for your IDE (after all it is simply using a config file to supply string replacements into nominated tags in your dproj template).

Comment: If that's all you are doing, why do you need a bespoke tool like that? Should be a trivial script using a language like Python. It never ceases to amaze me that so many people don't learn scripting languages.

Comment: see: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/